# Can we balance a redox reaction in basic medium just like as acidic medium and add OH- ions on both sides to cancel out H+ Ions?

Tags: redox

My teacher told me that the method (which I mentioned above)  is wrong but I find many references of saying the same method correct.

Comment: Provide an example please.

Comment: Probably the teacher would prefer introducing hydroxide ions directly rather than first using solvated hydrogen ions and then canceling them out.

Comment: Yes my teacher uses the same method as you mentioned here. I want to ask which is more correct or which is more accurate?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/140462/balancing-a-reaction-where-dichromate-ion-reacts-with-ethanol-to-give-criii-an/140478#140478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are of course two ways of balancing redox half-equations in basic solution : writing it directly with $\ce{OH-}$ ions or starting to do it in acidic conditions and then destroying the $\ce{H+}$ ions by adding $\ce{OH-}$ ions. Let's compare these two approaches with chromate ions being reduced to chromium(III).

**First method (acidic solution)**. The redox half-equation in acidic conditions is quickly obtained : $$\ce{CrO4^{2-} + 8 H+ + 3 e- -> Cr^{3+} + 4 H2O} \tag{1}$$ In basic solution, $\ce{8 OH-}$ have to be added on both sides to destroy the $\ce{8 H+}$ and get :$$\ce{CrO4^{2-} + 8 H2O + 3 e- -> Cr^{3+} + 4 H2O + 8 OH-} \tag{2}$$ which can be simplified thus : $$\ce{CrO4^{2-} + 4 H2O + 3 e- -> Cr^{3+} + 8 OH-} \tag{3}$$

**Second method (basic solution)**. Balancing the redox half-equation from $\ce{CrO4^{2-}}$ to $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ without $\ce{H+}$ is not so easy. Because the $4$ Oxygen atoms of the chromate ion are of course transformed  into $\ce{4OH-}$ ions, provided enough $\ce{H}$ are available. So this requires enough $\ce{H2O}$ on the left-hand-side to compensate for the $\ce{4 H}$ atoms included in these $\ce{4 OH-}$ : $\ce{2 H2O}$. But these $\ce{2 H2O}$ molecules bring new oxygen atoms. It is not obvious to see that, at the end, $\ce{4 H2O}$ (and not $2$) have to be added on the left-hand side. The final half-equation is :$$\ce{CrO4^{2-} + 4 H2O + 3 e- -> Cr^{3+} + 8 OH-} \tag{4}$$ This is equal to $(3)$. But it not so easy to obtain.

**Final remarks**. 1. Whatever the method used, it may be useful to state that the $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ ion does not exist and makes a precipitate in basic solution so that the final equation should be written $$\ce{CrO4^{2-} + 4 H2O + 3 e- -> Cr(OH)3 + 5 OH-} \tag{5}$$
2. The same reasoning could have been done starting from the ion $\ce{Cr2O7^{2-}}$ in acidic conditions. With the same conclusion.